# is windows 7 supported in ibm work light

Tags: windows-7

Is windows 7 is supported in ibm worklight 5.0.5. We are using mac os as we are targeting iOS and android environment as well. Is it possible to do the required installation for windows 7 environment in mac os. Initially windows 7 is supported in IBM worklight 5.0.5 or not? Can some one clear the above doubts as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Worklight 5.0.5 is supported for windows 7 and Mac os as in the [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838) of the official page of system requirement